# In Linux, how to batch copy files under different folders?

Tags: linux, awk

Let's say we have files

```
   a/xxx-data.html
   b/c/xxx-data.html
   d/xxx-data.html
```

And we want to make a copy of each file under the same folder but with different name pattern, like this

```
   a/yyy-data.html
   b/c/yyy-data.html
   d/yyy-data.html
```

I'm just curious, can we do this by combining 'find', 'xargs' and 'awk'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for any of these programs. Just

```
for file in **/xxx*.html; cp $file ${file/xxx/yyy}
```

is enough in zsh. The command for bash should be pretty similar.

HTH Chris

Answer (score 0):

This is just personal preference, but what I use is:

```
find | while read x; do y=`echo $x | awk '{ ... }'`; cp $x $y; done
```

Of course, I usually search for some specific files and don't generally use `awk` for simple transformations.